# how to stop multiple python script running if any script has error

Tags: python, linux

I have python script (installer.py) which runs multiple python and shell programs:

```
print "Going to run Script1"

os.system("python script1.py")

print "Going to run Script2"

os.system("python script2.py")
```

But I found that even if script1.py is not run because of its error, it simply moves on to run script2.py.

How to stop the script (installer.py) at the time of script1.py itself..

Comment: Why are you shelling out via os.system, rather than importing the script directly?

Comment: You may want to take a look into error handling via `try` and `except`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system` will return the exit status of the system call. Just check to see if your command executed correctly.

```
ret = os.system('python script1.py')
if ret != 0:
    # call failed
    raise Exception("System call failed with error code %d" % ret)


ret = os.system('python script2.py')
if ret != 0:
    # call failed
    raise Exception("System call failed with error code %d" % ret)
```

Comment: @suresh Please select an answer with a tick if it solved your original question. As for your follow on question: that sounds much more involved and should be asked as a new Stack Overflow question (it is not just a python question, but strays into the grounds of system administration).